# UITableViewController add item via method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a UISplitviewController and I am trying to add items to the table view.

right now I have two ways

1. Create a button and add it:

   ```
   UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
   ```

and this code runs when the button is clicked:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

and adds an item to the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

this way works.

This is what I am  trying to do:

```
- (void)GetRequest
{

    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

but this does not update the table view. I added a breakpoint and when I use the button I added, it goes into the table view, with the method it does not and I am calling the method via `[MasterController GetRequest];`

What am I doing wrong ?

I am calling GetRequest from another controller.

This is how MasterController is getting defined:

```
@interface DetailController ()
{

    MasterController *MasterController;

}
```

DetailController.m:

```
#import "MasterController.h"

@interface DetailController ()
{
     MasterController *MasterController;
}

@end

@implementation DetailController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
     MasterController = [[MasterController alloc]init];
}

[MasterController GetRequest];
```

MasterController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}

- (void)GetRequest
{

    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: How, and from where are you calling `GetRequest`? Which controller is that method in, and are you calling it from within that same controller?

Comment: In addition to @rdelmar, do you mean `[self GetRequest]` instead of `[self.GetRequest]` ?

Comment: GetRequest is in the same controller that tableView is in. I am calling GetRequest from another controller, and I can see its going into the GetRequest method when I trigger it.

Comment: Is self.tableView non-nil when `GetRequest` is called from this other controller?

Comment: I put a breakpoint where GetRequest is being called, inside self at the time when the breakpoint his, self.tableView does not exists.

Comment: You said you call it with, `[MasterController GetRequest]`. What is MasterController? How are you getting a reference to the controller with the table view? I'm guessing that you are creating a new instance which is not the one you see on screen.

Comment: You still haven't show us how are you getting reference to  the MasterController. By the way, it's really not the best practice to name your variable exactly the same as it's class name.

Comment: @ArturOlszak I have updated my question....that is all I have in DetailController that references MasterController

Comment: So in fact it was wrong, and I can see that someone already gave you an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, with this line,  `MasterController = [[MasterController alloc]init]`, you're creating a new instance that has nothing to do with the one you see on screen. You need to get a reference to the master controller that you already have in the split view controller. From the detail view controller, you can get that like so,

```
MasterController = self.splitViewController.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

The split view controller has a viewControllers property, and the one at index 0 is the master, and the one at index 1 is the detail. BTW, you should start your ivars and method names with a lower class letter.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewController` doesn't really work that way.
If you subclass it you need to implement several methods that tells the table what data it has -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

To add new rows you just need to add objects to `self.objects` and call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

It'll basically be -

```
- (void)GetRequest
{

    if (!self.objects) {
        self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this did not work, I can see the items being added to the object, but they are not being added to my tableView

Comment: I am calling GetRequest from another controller